# How to compare the data type of a query value in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How to compare the data type of a query result value? For example, to check if something is an 'interval'

```
select pg_typeof(current_timestamp - '2020-01-01 00:00') = 'interval';
```

gives the error

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type oid: "interval"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the string `'interval'`  to a type OID:

```
select pg_typeof(current_timestamp - '2020-01-01 00:00') = 'interval'::regtype;
```

Comment: This could have been determined with the query `select pg_typeof(pg_typeof(current_timestamp - '2020-01-01 00:00'));`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a safe query you can use the one below;

```
select
  pg_typeof(current_timestamp - '2020-01-01 00:00') 
    IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 
to_regtype('interval');
```

`to_regtype` returns null if the argument ('interval' our case) is a non existing type. Because of that we use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` operator which returns false with `NULL` value operand